# Webpack hot module replacement in server code

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

All the webpack examples I have looked at so far deal with client side hot module replacement, for example: [this](http://andrewhfarmer.com/webpack-hmr-tutorial/) and [this](https://github.com/glenjamin/webpack-hot-middleware/blob/master/example/server.js).

According to the webpack document, one can use EITHER webpack-dev-server OR middlewares (webpack-dev-webpack-dev-middleware and webpack-hot-middleware, along with `webpack-hot-middleware/client` in a config `entry`, and integrated into e.g. express js) to enable hot module replacement for client side codes

Is it possible to enable hot module replacement for server side codes? The document does shows an [example](http://webpack.github.io/docs/hot-module-replacement.html)

```js
var requestHandler = require("./handler.js");
var server = require("http").createServer();
server.on("request", requestHandler);
server.listen(8080);

// check if HMR is enabled
if(module.hot) {
    // accept update of dependency
    module.hot.accept("./handler.js", function() {
        // replace request handler of server
        server.removeListener("request", requestHandler);
        requestHandler = require("./handler.js");
        server.on("request", requestHandler);
    });
}
```

The document is quite spare in explanation.

So the question is, how would hot module replacement be implemented in server side code without restarting the server? (At the moment, I have nodemon watching server side code to restart the server on file changes)

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I am struggling with exactly the same thing and I would die for a simple running example *with some explanation*. Webpack remains pure magic to me...

Comment: I finally created my own example at https://github.com/aunz/mwb/tree/master/examples/basicApp. Have a look.

Comment: This is looking good, thanks!

Comment: @Green, can you share any links or articles where you got inspired to build this? Looking over the tool I can understand partially what is going on. Would really appreaciate it.

Comment: @VladNicula, 1) server codes are watched in [this line](https://github.com/aunz/mwb/blob/master/examples/basicApp/tool/dev.js#L86) and run as a forked child in [this line](https://github.com/aunz/mwb/blob/master/examples/basicApp/tool/dev.js#L94). 2) On code changes, a signal 'hmr' is sent to the server in [this line](https://github.com/aunz/mwb/blob/master/examples/basicApp/tool/dev.js#L89). The 'hrm' signal is handled through the "inspired" original [signal.js](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/hot/signal.js) which either carrys out hot update or reload.

Answer (score 2):

Hot reloading server middleware bundled with Webpack is actually much easier than hot reloading client side bundles for two reasons:

1. You don't have to handle server / client communication.
2. Middleware is almost always necessarily stateless so you don't need to concern yourself with state preservation.

This means you can ignore all the moving parts associated with client side hot module reloading such as WebSockets as well as teaching your code to update itself through `module.hot.accept` / `module.hot.dispose`.

Here's an example:

```js
// ./src/middleware.js
module.exports = (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World');
};
```

```js
// webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    target: 'node',
    entry: './src/middleware.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, './dist'),
        filename: 'middleware.js',
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
    }
};
```

```js
// ./src/index.js
const express = require('express');
const config = require('webpack.config.js');

const app = express();
const queue = [];
let latestMiddleware;

webpack(config).watch(() => {
    // re-require new middleware
    delete require.cache[require.resolve('./dist/middleware.js')]
    latestMiddleware = require('./dist/middleware.js');
    // pass buffered requests to latestMiddleware
    while (queue.length) latestMiddleware.apply(void 0, queue.shift());
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (latestMiddleware) {
        latestMiddleware(req, res, next);
        return;
    }
    queue.push([req, res, next]);
});

app.listen(6060);
```

As you can see the fact that there's no state to worry about means the `latestMiddleware` can simply reference the new bundled middleware without having to write custom logic to update other modules in the dependency graph.

Incidentally, this is the exact same technique used by [`webpack-hot-server-middleware`](https://github.com/60frames/webpack-hot-server-middleware), the only difference is webpack-hot-server-middleware is more geared towards hot reloading universal apps on the server.

Answer (score -1):

This can be a good starting point, https://github.com/jlongster/backend-with-webpack.

Comment: For some reasons, I couldn't get the example running

Comment: The codebase posted is accompanied by a series of 3 articles about the reassons the author chose that specific patch. The most relevant on is the second part where he talks about serverside webpack bundling: http://jlongster.com/Backend-Apps-with-Webpack--Part-II. However, his approach does not support hot realoding on the server. He always restarts on change, as he explains in the article, and as you can see in the source code of his gulpfile: https://github.com/jlongster/backend-with-webpack/blob/master/gulpfile.js#L143

Comment: Using gulp && webpack? That is lazy solution... No thanks. :)