# How to use nodemon while developing for server but NOT recompile a webpack client config?

Tags: webpack, nodemon

I'm setting up a universal react app and I want the experience while developing to be fluid.

Right now, when I run `nodemon` on my server entry file:

1. it creates an `express` app
2. it compiles webpack for the client
3. does `app.use(compiledClientWebpack)`
4. makes some routes
5. then does `app.listen()`

I have `nodemon` ignoring my client folder so that changes to the client folder are hot reloaded by webpack. That's great.

However in the server folder, `nodemon` will restart the server entry file, which recompiles webpack for the client even though the client webpack has not changed.

Obviously this is unnecessary wait time that I would like to remove. However I'm not entirely sure how to do this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I wouldn't recommend using nodemon if your server compiles a webpack bundle, instead I would recommend one of the following two approaches:

1) Use something like [`webpack-hot-server-middleware`](https://github.com/60frames/webpack-hot-server-middleware) to hot replace your server bundle.

2) Implement server side hot module replacement as [described here](https://github.com/webpack/docs/issues/45)

> DISCLAIMER: I'm the author of `webpack-hot-server-middleware` so my opinion is `webpack-hot-server-middleware` is the better approach as there's less moving parts, especially if you're already using `webpack-dev-middleware` and `webpack-hot-middleware` (You can read a bit about how it works here -- [Webpack hot module replacement in server code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34101783/webpack-hot-module-replacement-in-server-code/40165550#40165550)). Additionally you can find a [working implementation here](https://github.com/60frames/react-boilerplate).